# Free a linked list in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to free these linked lists and i get no compile errors but valgrind is saying "30 allocs, 14 frees, 6,377 bytes allocated ".
Shouldn't this function wipe all the allocations in the lists.

```
void free_mem(struct medico *head_m, struct paciente *head_p , struct consulta *head_c)
{   
    struct medico *tmp_m = NULL; 
    struct paciente *tmp_p = NULL; 
    struct consulta *tmp_c = NULL; 

    while (!head_m) { 
        tmp_m = head_m->next;
        free(head_m);
        head_m = tmp_m;
    }

    while (!head_p) { 
        tmp_p = head_p->next;
        free(head_p);
        head_p = tmp_p;
    }

    while (!head_c) { 
        tmp_c = head_c->next;
        free(head_c);
        head_c = tmp_c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Once you rewrite `while()` loops into `for(;;)` loops, you'll see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop conditions are wrong:

```
while (!head_m)
```

If `head_m` is not NULL, the loop is never executed. To fix, remove `!`:

```
while (head_m)
```

Comment: Thank you ! This was really a noob mistake -.- And so easy to spot everything is being freed now.